# Login reroutes to login?error when user credentials are correct

Tags: spring-boot, templates, model-view-controller, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am relatively new to coding and working on a group project for extra practice using Java MVC, Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, and a SQL database. We are also using spring security. My feature, user authentication, has been very challenging and I would love more experienced developer's eyes and opinions.
From the user side I can register (this information gets passed to SQL and stores it as a username and hashed password). Then I log in and it reroutes to login?error even when the username and password are correct. I get no error codes in the network tab, nor my IDE IntelliJ. I have used the debugger and that is not coming up with any error messages either. I reviewed the logic and did not catch any errors, but maybe one of you will?

I have had to do some workarounds with Spring security and have implemented these permissions in a securityConfig file:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/register").permitAll() // Whitelist the register page for unauthenticated access
                .antMatchers("/styles/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/home").authenticated() // Require authentication for /home
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // All other requests require authentication
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll() // Customize login page if needed
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll(); // Customize logout page if needed

    }
    }
```

Right now all the GetMapping and PostMapping is in a controller called AuthenticationController which looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/login")
    public String displayLoginForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("loginFormDTO", new LoginFormDTO());
        model.addAttribute("title", "Log In");
        return "login";
    }
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String processLoginForm(@ModelAttribute @Valid LoginFormDTO loginFormDTO,
                                   Errors errors, HttpServletRequest request,
                                   Model model) {

        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("title", "Log In");
            return "login";
        }

        User theUser = userRepository.findByUsername(loginFormDTO.getUsername());

        if (theUser == null) {
            errors.rejectValue("username", "user.invalid", "The given username does not exist");
            model.addAttribute("title", "Log In");
            return "login";
        }

        String password = loginFormDTO.getPassword();

        if (!theUser.isMatchingPassword(password)) {
            errors.rejectValue("password", "password.invalid", "Invalid password");
            model.addAttribute("title", "Log In");
            return "login";
        }

        setUserInSession(request.getSession(), theUser);

        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String displayHomepage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String username = getUserFromSession(request.getSession()).getUsername();
        model.addAttribute("username", username);
        return "home";
    }
```

Lastly, we have templates in src/main/resources/templates and in the templates folder I have thymeleaf views login.html and home.html that look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/" lang="en" >
<head th:replace="fragments :: head"></head>
<title>Login</title>
<body class="container">

<form method="post" th:action="@{/login}" >
  <div>
    <label th:for="username">Username
      <input class="form-control" th:field="${loginFormDTO.username}" type="text">
    </label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label th:for="password">Password
      <input class="form-control" th:field="${loginFormDTO.password}" type="password">
    </label>

  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Log In"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The home.html thymeleaf view looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
<script th:src="@{/script.js}"></script>
<h1>My Recipe Manager Homepage</h1>
<div id="container">
    <!-- List of recipes will be added here dynamically from the JS static file-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Last, but not least, we are using gradle and my build.gradle file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.13'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'org.liftoff.DigitalRecipeManager'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '11'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    implementation 'de.vinado.spring:dkim-javamail:1.2.2'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have exhausted my resources and spent days troubleshooting, researching, etc. and would appreciate any developers input who have experience using this tech stack and want to give a humble coding newbie some advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows:

1. Remove the `@PostMapping("/login")` method from your `AuthenticationController`. The POST is handled by Spring Security itself.
2. Replace the `@GetMapping("/login")` with just rendering the `login` template. For example:

```
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
        if (userDetails == null) {
            return "login";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }
```

3. Adjust the `login.html` template to use `name="username"` and `name="password"` instead of the `th:field` attributes you have now. (See [login.html](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/taming-thymeleaf-sources/blob/2.0.0/chapter16/src/main/resources/templates/login.html) for an example).
4. Update your `SecurityConfig` with a `UserDetailsService`:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
```

(See [WebSecurityConfiguration.java](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/taming-thymeleaf-sources/blob/2.0.0/chapter16/src/main/java/com/tamingthymeleaf/application/infrastructure/security/WebSecurityConfiguration.java) for an example)

5. Create an implementation of `UserDetailsService` to be injected into the `SecurityConfig`. It links Spring Security to the users in your database. For example:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class DatabaseUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) { 
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(new Email(username)) 
                                  .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(
                                          format("User with email %s could not be found", username))); 

        return new ApplicationUserDetails(user); 
    }
}
```